# Running .NET Core Web API with Kestrel under https as Windows service

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, windows-services, kestrel

The idea is, I would like to run a .NET Core Web API with Kestrel enabled and configured to expose https, the service is intended for internal use and a js application should call localhost:someport under https.

I am installing the API as a Windows service via SC cli and it installs fine. As soon as I start the service I get the following error:

> Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date

But when I run it from VS, it runs just fine and accepts the certificate without a hitch.

The certificate is also installed locally in the Trusted Root CA.

> Application: DunaPrintServiceWP.exe
> CoreCLR Version: 5.0.1121.47308
> .NET Version: 5.0.11
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
>
> For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at DunaPrintServiceWP.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\OneCM.StoreCRM\DunaPrintServiceWP\Program.cs:line 19

`launchSettings.Json`:

```
///trimmed for brevity

 "DunaPrintServiceWP": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "externalUrlConfiguration": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9123;https://localhost:9124",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        
        .UseWindowsService(config =>
        {
            config.ServiceName = "DFPS_WP";
        })
        
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls();

            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                var port = 9124;
                var pfxFilePath = @"c:\certs\bella.pfx";
                // I've hard-coded it here just to make it easier to see what's going on.
                var pfxPassword = "Asd.Zxc1@#";

                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions =>
                {
                    // Enable support for HTTP1 and HTTP2 (required if you want to host gRPC endpoints)
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                    // Configure Kestrel to use a certificate from a local .PFX file for hosting HTTPS
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(pfxFilePath, pfxPassword);
                });
            });
        });
```

appSettings.json

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "HTTP": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:9123"
      },
      "HTTPS": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:9124",
        "ClientCertificateMode": "NoCertificate",
        "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2",
        "SslProtocols": [ "Tls13", "Tls12", "Tls11", "Tls" ],
        "Certificate": { "AllowInvalid": true }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: My two cents: Configure the `Log On` user of the service, try to use your current user, and not `LOCAL System Account`. I suspect that you have the certificate on the USER partition and not on the MACHINE. There are three certificate stores (User, Service, and Computer). You can check its launching `mmc` and add `Certiticates snap-in`